# How to create square image thumbnails using the foundation framework with CSS

Tags: css, frameworks, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to achieve this using foundation 3.2.5:
http://foundation.zurb.com/old-docs/f3/clearing.php

I want the thumbnails to show up as squares with the same size. This here is the code that i took from their website and which they are using:

```
              <div class="row">
            <div class="four columns">
              <ul class="block-grid three-up mobile-two-up" data-clearing>
                <li><a href="http://placekitten.com/g/1000/1000"><img data-caption="Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna." src="http://placekitten.com/g/1000/1000"></a></li>
                <li><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/1000/900"></li>
                <li><a href="http://placekitten.com/g/1000/800"><img data-caption="Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet." src="http://placekitten.com/g/1000/800"></a></li>
                <li><img data-caption="Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum." src="http://placekitten.com/g/1000/700"></li>
                <li><a href="http://placekitten.com/g/1000/600"><img data-caption="Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod." src="http://placekitten.com/g/1000/600"></a></li>
                <li><img data-caption="Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit." src="http://placekitten.com/g/1000/500"></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
```

However when using this with foundation 3 it wont resize the images to squares. Any ideas what i might be missing?

Answer (score 0):

Mmmm... well the code you pasted is not the same from zurb.com, in fact the original code uses the same size for all the images.

```
<ul class="block-grid three-up" data-clearing>
  <li><a href="http://placekitten.com/g/1000/800"><img data-caption="Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna." src="http://placekitten.com/g/100/100"></a></li>
  <li><img data-caption="Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna." src="http://placekitten.com/g/1000/800"></li>
  <li><a href="http://placekitten.com/g/1000/800"><img data-caption="Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna." src="http://placekitten.com/g/100/100"></a></li>
  <li><img data-caption="Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna." src="http://placekitten.com/g/1000/800"></li>
  <li><a href="http://placekitten.com/g/1000/800"><img data-caption="Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna." src="http://placekitten.com/g/100/100"></a></li>
  <li><img data-caption="Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna." src="http://placekitten.com/g/1000/800"></li>
</ul>
```

Now, what you are trying to achieve, could be done using a Jquery Plugin like https://code.google.com/p/resize-crop/